# fatal: Not a git repository: folderAname/../../.git/modules/folderBname/folderAname

Tags: git, github

Steps:

```
git init
```

Reinitialized existing Git repository in /opt/stuff/.git/

```
git add .
```

fatal: Not a git repository: folderNameA/../../.git/modules/folderNameB/folderNameA

```
git status
```

shows several untracked files and
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/myRepo.git
```

No output

```
git add .
```

fatal: Not a git repository: folderNameA/../../.git/modules/folderNameB/folderNameA

Not sure what's going on here.  Any ideas welcome.  I thought there might have already been a .git folder present in a deeper directory so I also tried:

```
rm -rf .git
```

... and repeated the steps above but got the same error.

Comment: "*Reinitialized existing Git repository in `/opt/stuff/.git/`*" Does that mean that you're current working directory is actually `/opt/stuff/.git/` when you try to run `git init`? Um...why are you trying to run that command inside of the `.git` folder? That folder represents your repo metadata in a non-bare repo...you're not really supposed to run Git commands inside that directory.

Comment: @Cupcake No, it means the cwd is `/opt/stuff/` -- Try running git init in an empty folder and look at the message.

Comment: Are you using Git submodules?

Comment: @PatrikOldsberg `git init` in a newly created folder gives: Initialized empty Git repository in /home/pi/gitTestFolder/.git/   the /.git/ part doesn't seem right but I initialized it in /home/pi/gitTestFolder/

Comment: @Cupcake this repo was probably cloned from github.  Is that what you mean?  I sanitized it with `rm -rf .git`